# VBA to add cell values on match between two cells

Tags: excel, vba, loops, match

I have the following code which looks for a match between worksheet 1 column C and worksheet 2 column E, and when there is a match it will copy over the value in certain other cells on the same row. It works well, however when there is more than one match between worksheet 1 column C and worksheet 2 column E, each subsequent match is just re-writing over the original.

How can I code it so that the first match will copy over the values, but then any subsequent matches will simply add their values, not write over them?

Thank you in advance!

```
 Sub OnClick()
 'Define your variables
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, cel As Range, i As Long

'Assign your worksheet variables
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PLANNER_ONGOING_DISPLAY_SHEET")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("REPORT_DOWNLOAD")

    'First loop through each cell in Sheet2, column E, start at row 2 to account
    'for header row) to get the value to find in sheet1, column C.
    For Each cel In ws2.Range("E2:E" & ws2.Range("E" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

        'Then loop through each cell in Sheet1, Column C. If you get a match, then
        'copy the value from Sheet2, Column B, cel.row to Sheet1, Column S, i row.
        For i = 2 To ws1.Range("L" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            If cel.Value = ws1.Cells(i, 3).Value Then
                ws1.Cells(i, 3).Offset(, 16).Value = cel.Offset(, 3).Value
                ws1.Cells(i, 3).Offset(, 15).Value = cel.Offset(, 4).Value
                ws1.Cells(i, 3).Offset(, 17).Value = cel.Offset(, 7).Value
            End If

        Next i 'loops through every used cell in Column C for all matches
    Next cel 'loop to the next cell in Sheets2, Columns E

End Sub
```

Comment: Chance `ws1.Cells(i, 3).Offset(, 16).Value = cel.Offset(, 3).Value` to `ws1.Cells(i, 3).Offset(, 16).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 3).Offset(, 16).Value & cel.Offset(, 3).Value`. You will have to do this for all 3 statements and format the text how you want it to appear. Saying that, there are much more efficient ways of doing what you are attempting to do (i.e. capture you range in an array,build a results array and transpose it back to your worksheet)

Comment: So there might already be values in the cells you're copying to, that you need to overwrite, correct?

Comment: @M.Schalk Yes so there are values in worksheet 1 that can be overwritten after the first match, but then any subsequent matches i would like the cell values added to the now overwritten cells, not replaced. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Zac Would you be able to help me out with a more efficient way? Currently the table I am looking through for matches has 11,000 or so rows, so any efficiency boost would really help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you requested in your comments, here is a more efficient version that does what you're trying to do:

```
Sub OnClick()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PLANNER_ONGOING_DISPLAY_SHEET")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("REPORT_DOWNLOAD")

Dim arr_1 As Variant, arr_2 As Variant, arr_result As Variant
arr_1 = ws1.Range("C2:C" & ws2.Range("L" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
arr_2 = ws2.Range("E2:L" & ws2.Range("E" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2

ReDim arr_result(LBound(arr_2) To UBound(arr_2), 1 To 3)

Dim i As Long, j As Long

For i = LBound(arr_1, 1) To UBound(arr_1, 1)
    For j = LBound(arr_2, 1) To UBound(arr_2, 1)

        If arr_1(i, 1) = arr_2(j, 1) Then
            'use this if you're handling numbers
            arr_result(i, 1) = arr_result(i, 1) + arr_2(j, 5)
            arr_result(i, 2) = arr_result(i, 2) + arr_2(j, 4)
            arr_result(i, 3) = arr_result(i, 3) + arr_2(j, 8)

            'use this if you're handling strings
            arr_result(i, 1) = arr_result(i, 1) & arr_2(j, 5)
            arr_result(i, 2) = arr_result(i, 2) & arr_2(j, 4)
            arr_result(i, 3) = arr_result(i, 3) & arr_2(j, 8)
        End If

    Next j
Next i

ws1.Cells(2, 18).Resize(UBound(arr_result, 1), 3).Value2 = arr_result

End Sub
```

This procedure puts all relevant data into arrays and writes the desired results into `arr_result`.Then all the values stored inside `arr_result` are put into your output range.

Comment: This looks like it works! I think I've got my cell references off though as it's pasting in the wrong cells. Would you be able to update this code if I said that on a match:

- The cell in worksheet 2 column H is being added to the cell in worksheet 1 column S
- The cell in worksheet 2 column I is being added to the cell in worksheet 1 column R
- The cell in worksheet 2 column L is being added to the cell in worksheet 1 column T

If you could do that you would get my unconditional appreciation!

Comment: Your cell references were correct, I just missed that detail. It's an easy fix though, just replace that 15 in the last with an 18, I also edited my answer.